# Mutating a state from one module to another Vuex

Tags: vuex

I'm pretty new to Vuex and am having difficulty understanding how to handle a state change from one module to another. Currently, I have a module called transactions which does an Ajax request and if successful it should close the Modal that is open. I have my modal state set in a separate module called General. I originally tried to set the General State of modal but committing my general mutation closeModal. I realized this won't work and as it sounds like Mutations aren't supposed to do this sort of heavy lifting. I've searched for another method to handle this sort of work and have been lead to Actions but I'm not clear on how to implement it or if it is even supposed to do this kind of work. Would someone please let me know if an Action is the correct method for this problem or if there is another way I should be addressing things.

I have a module called transactions that is running an ajax request and should close a modal if successful. For the sake of this issue, I've simplified my module.

```
const Transactions = {
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
    CONFIRM_TRANSACTION_CANCEL: function(state) {
      this.$store.commit('CLOSE_MODAL')
    }
}
```

And I also have a second module called general which I want to use for general state management and error handling. I'm attempting to call a mutation from transactions into this general module.

```
const General = {
  state: {
    modalState: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    ...

    CLOSE_MODAL: function(state) {
      state.modalState = null
    },

    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not make a commit inside a mutation. Mutations are only to change the state.

You could do this in two ways:

1.- Using Vue's Watch *spying* transaction state. Then, if the transaction is correctly done, you dispatch an action to close the Modal.

2.- You can dispatch an action to close the modal inside the action that launches the ajax call (after the success).

```
apiCall({ dispatch, commit }) {
  api.get('/transaction')
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch('closeModal');
      commit('TRANSACTION_SUCCESS', response);
    })
    .catch((error) => commit('TRANSACTION_ERROR', error));
}
```

These methods below are done with thinking of the modal as it should use vuex too but, if you want to simplify you can just:

3.- Pass the status of the transaction that comes from vuex directly to the modal by prop and handle the modal with it.

Comment: So if I was to use the first method you would suggest creating a property in transactions state to track if the transaction was successful or not and then have my component mutate the General module to close the modal? I'm going to have to do this a lot throughout the app so I'm hoping for a method with the least amount of code. I'm don't really understand the second method could you elaborate?

Comment: If the modal is only used for this, why not include the watch inside the modal component itself? So when modal's watch detects that the transaction is successful, it will dispatch the closing action. You won't repeat code.

Comment: As for the 2nd, I'm gonna edit the answer with some code to help you visualize it.

Comment: Hm yeah maybe a watch on the modal would work but I think it would require some rewriting to get it to work app-wide. The second answer seems more intriguing (I'm going to need this sort of thing for error handling as well) to me but I still don't fully get it. I appreciate the help. I'm going to play around with this and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Jleibham just added a new one.